# Inetmgr(iis6) from run dialog and command line

Tags: windows

How do i change the behaviour of Run Task - inetmgr - so it runs the IIS6 compatible version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just dug around a bit and found that typing 'inet' instead does the trick